# Unable to assign value for array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a functional typescript component. Inside that I am trying assign values to a array by getting values from json file. I am able to get values from json. But if I try to assign value to an array. I am getting error in chrome inspect like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined`

Below is my code,

```
let val:{data:string,value:string}[]=[{data:"1",value:"vals"},];
const getDetails=():data[]=>{
    
    for(let j=0;j<mydata.length;j++){
        val[j].data=mydata[j].id;  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined
        val[j].value=mydata[j].name; //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
        console.log(mydata[j].name); //getting values correctly
        console.log(mydata[j].id); //getting values correctly
    }
    return val;
  }
```

****NOTE:I referred lots of stack questions similar to this error. But none resolved my error.****

I have defined the property which is data and value. But eventhough I am getting the error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If `mydata.length` is more than `val.length` you'll likely see this error. In this case, all it takes is for `myData` to have at least 2 elements in it. Can you update your question to include all the relevant code, i.e. what `myData` is, and walk us through the code and what you want it to do?

Comment: @DrewReese yes, initially val has only one value in it. I am trying to assign more values from mydata.

Comment: @DrewReese then how to make my val to accept more data

Comment: Try this: `for(let j=0;j<mydata.length - 1;j++)`

Comment: Sure, the array exists, and at some point you hit `val[j]` that doesn't have a defined value yet, so you can't access a `data` property.

Comment: @RyanLe thanks. but, that didn't worked fr me

Comment: @DrewReese thanks. Could you explain me what should I do. Because, I am new to react and typescript.

Comment: @DrewReese I need to assign value to the array which has two property in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you are indexing into the `val` array and hitting undefined values. You can't access properties of undefined.

You can iterate over the `myData` array and for any indices where `val[index]` is undefined you create a new object reference.

```
let val: { data: string, value: string }[] = [{ data: "1", value: "vals"}];

const getDetails = ():data[] => {
  myData.forEach((el, i) => {
    if (!val[i]) val[i] = {}; // create object if not exist
    val[i] = {
      ...val[i],
      data: el.id,
      value: el.name
    };
  });
  return val;
}
```

If your code supports Nullish Coalescing

```
const getDetails = ():data[] => {
  myData.forEach((el, i) => {
    val[i] = {
      ...val[i] ?? {}, // provide fallback object if not exist
      data: el.id,
      value: el.name
    };
  });
  return val;
}
```